# How to remove char from regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm not got, yet, with regex. I've been trying to break my head to get this to work.

I need a regex that allows the user to enter

- Any alphabetical char (a-z)
- Any number
- For special char only "-" and "_".
- "@" is not allowed.

I got this but no dice. `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`

Thanks

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]`. Your regexp is backwards, it's matching characters that are *not* in the set you describe, not matching the characters you want to allow, because of `^`.

Comment: Hey @Barmar thank you! But that still doesn't solve the problem :( The "@" shouldn't be allowed at all and the "-", "_" should be optional.

Comment: That was just the pattern for a single character. You quantify it and anchor it ensure that only those characters are matched in the whole string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[\w-]+$
```

will match a string following the rules you describe. `\w` matches letters, digits, or underscore, then it adds `-` to that set. Anchoring with `^` and `$` requires all the characters in the string to match this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

remove `^` character in square brackets because is negative ranges, add some `\-\_` to allow '-' and '_' character inside square brackets

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+
```